# Ruby on Rails file authorization under RAILS_ROOT/public

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I am looking for a way of running a type of `check_access` to my files located under my public folder. I heard about RAILS_ROOT/private. I believe this directory provides my demands.

But I don't have deep information about it. The core idea of mine is serving files to  only use which has the ability to view/download the files. Such as a posted pictures, I don't want them to be public. Currently, all the people who have knowledge of the URL pointing to the correct directory can access all files.

PS: The files under /public dir are uploaded via carrierwave gem.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know where you got the notion that `RAILS_ROOT/private` does anything at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need access control for your files you don't want to serve them from your public folder. Your public folder is server either by `ActionDispatch::StaticFile` or directly by your web server - neither of which provide the kind of access controll you want.

Instead you would create a controller which serves up the files:

```
class FilesController < ActionController::Metal
  before_action :authenticate! # you need to implement this
  before_action :authorize!    # you need to implement this

  # GET /files/:filename
  def show
    path = Rails.root.join(
      'uploads', # can be any directory you want really
       # avoids a malicous user being able to use for example '../../secret/password'
       ActiveStorage::Filename.new(params[:file_name]).sanitized
    )
    if File.exist?(path)
      send_file path
    else
      head :not_found
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I will be trying this.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the permissions in your database and then you can add a check before displaying the url of a file to the users. You shouldn't keep the files in public folder if you want them to be restricted.